# SELECT stuck giving results from the query result cache, though table has changed

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, cache

A process that runs every two minutes or so started to misbehave. We noticed it was because the cursor fetched repeatedly 0 rows, even if indeed there were new rows satisfying the conditions in the *where* conditions.

The `select` of the cursor is like this:

```
SELECT 
       colk, col2
FROM 
       a_table
WHERE 
       status = 'A' AND
       processed = 'N'
ORDER BY 
       mod_date DESC NULLS LAST, ins_date;
```

For every fetched row, the process does things (not lengthy things), then it updates that row through the unique key `colk`, like this:

```
UPDATE 
       a_table
SET 
       processed = 'Y',
       mod_date = DECODE(:t, 0, mod_date, SYSDATE),
WHERE 
       colk = :just_fetched_colk AND
       status ='A';
```

When there are no other rows, we commit.

Before the process runs, when the process is running and after the process is run, there can be events that call a “task” which inserts or updates some rows (one per event). The update is the same as the one above, except that `processed` is set to N. New rows are inserted with `processed` to N and `ins_date` given by `SYSDATE`.

At some point, as said, at each run of the process no rows were fetched, even if there were hundreds thousand changes “accumulated” in several days.

---

“Professional” explanation after analysis: when the *result cache* is enabled, there are “restrictions” you must comply with. If you don't, you can't expect Oracle surely invalidates the result cache, since it is not necessarily able to *track* dependencies. Our update uses `SYSDATE`, while the `select` does an *order by* the date-column we update using that `SYSDATE`. This causes problems.

In my opinion this is a totally wrong and imaginative explanation, and also a wrong interpretation of the limits of the result cache I've read about in [Tuning the result cache](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA616), in particular in the section [Setting the Result Cache Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA640), second paragraph.

This apart and “technical details” apart, I can't buy any of that without calling this behaviour a **dangerous bug** (so, our fix is a *workaround* for an Oracle bug, not a patch for a mistake of ours). In fact I am convinced that if rows in the table the `select` “depends” on are updated (no matter how), then Oracle **must** invalidate the result cache — I am also sure there's nothing hard to track in our `select`…

If Oracle does not invalidate the cache when it blatantly should, it fails to assure a basic promise software usually relies on: shouldn't a `select` see the most recent “situation” left by all the committed transactions? (If not the most recent, at least not totally stuck to a certain moment…)

---

The answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5247/functioning-of-oracles-server-result-cache), suggested while picking an explanatory title, seems to confirm I am right (following the spirit and the links to the [query result cache](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=503)). Therefore the question isn't «are their explanations reasonable?» anymore.

It becomes: any idea of what's going on? Similar experiences? (I can't find any). I know, too broad. Unfortunately, I am not able to give more details. In particular I wonder if the suggested *workaround* can be considered a safe fix, since in fact we can't be sure we identified the problem properly, or rather it will be more safe to keep the `NO_RESULT_CACHE` hint.

(The exact release is 11.2.0.4.0, 64bit)

Comment: If it won't be deleted before, I will delete myself this question if it looks a total waste of space and time, if it does not foster interesting answers, if it gets heavily downvoted.

Comment: Did you set the result cache mode to `force`? System or session-wide?

Comment: Not me, but yes, as far as I know: the result cache mode is `force`; I think, but I can't be sure (how can I check?), it's system-wide.

Comment: `show parameter result_cache`

Comment: result_cache_mode (string) is `AUTO`. (About the system or session-wide topic, how can I check?)

Comment: `AUTO` isn't documented. I suggest you open an SR, playing with undocumented settings is a bit risky.

Comment: Not in my direct possibilities, unluckly... I've already repeated more times it must be a bug; *they* even refused to acknowledge this... I want just to be sure there's nothing wrong in the part I am in charge of and to have an idea about if we must keep eyes open since we are not addressing the problem properly.  We'll apply the workaround "they" suggest (in their parlance, we'll comply with the required "restriction") (With "they" I mean all the professionals in charge of the database stuffs)

Comment: Look, you're using undocumented parameters. Unless Oracle specifically advised you to do that, you're on your own. Either you open an SR to see if they feel like helping anyway, or you revert to supported/documented parameters. If you can reproduce the bug with a supported configuration, then you can claim it is a bug.

Comment: Thanks Mat. I will try to explain the issue and the risk (there should be an Oracle consultant on site, side by side with the other "local" folks, so I hope the choice was in fact advised and agreed)